# appending one multidimensional array to another array element and encode to json php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have two multidimensional arrays as follows:

One for Categories:

```
$categories = array (
        array("slug1", "label1"),
        array("slug2","label2"),
        array("slug3","label3"), 
        array("slug4","label4")
    );
```

and another for subcategories:

```
$subCategories = array (
        array("sub-slug1","sub-label1"),
        array("sub-slug2","sub-label2"),
        array("sub-slug3","sub-label3"), 
        array("sub-slug4","sub-label4")
    );
```

I can generate the json for only the categories as:

```
foreach ($categories as $category) {

        $catArray[] = array("category-slug" => $category[0], "category-label" => $category[1], "subcategory-slug" => $subCategory[0], "subcategory-label" => $subCategory[1] );
    }
echo json_encode($catArray);
```

Now, I have to append the whole subcategory array to one of the category, say **slug1** so that the format becomes:

```
array("category-slug" => $category[0], "category-label" => $category[1], "subcategory-slug" => $subCategory[0], "subcategory-label" => $subCategory[1] )
```

**UPDATE**
The output should be in following format:

```
[
{
    "category-slug": "slug1",
    "category-label": "label1",
    "subcategory": [
    {
        "subcategory-slug": "sub-slug1",
        "subcategory-label": "sub-label1",
    },
    {
        "subcategory-slug": "sub-slug1",
        "subcategory-label": "sub-label1",
    },
    {
        "subcategory-slug": "sub-slug1",
        "subcategory-label": "sub-label1",
    },
    {
        "subcategory-slug": "sub-slug1",
        "subcategory-label": "sub-label1",
    }]
},
{
    "category-slug": "slug2",
    "category-label": "label2",
    "subcategory": []
},
{
    "category-slug": "slug3",
    "category-label": "label3",
    "subcategory": []
    }
},
{
    "category-slug": "slug4",
    "category-label": "label4",
    "subcategory": []    
    }
}
]
```

Comment: You expected outcome is unclear. based on input values can you show you expected outcome?

Answer (score 0):

If `$categories` and `$subCategories` arrays have the same order of items - it would be enough to use the following approach:

```
$catArray = [];
foreach ($categories as $k => $category) {
    $catArray[] = [
        "category-slug" => $category[0],
        "category-label" => $category[1],
        "subcategory-slug" => $subCategories[$k][0],
        "subcategory-label" => $subCategories[$k][1]
    ];
}

echo json_encode($catArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "category-slug": "slug1",
        "category-label": "label1",
        "subcategory-slug": "sub-slug1",
        "subcategory-label": "sub-label1"
    },
    {
        "category-slug": "slug2",
        "category-label": "label2",
        "subcategory-slug": "sub-slug2",
        "subcategory-label": "sub-label2"
    },
    {
        "category-slug": "slug3",
        "category-label": "label3",
        "subcategory-slug": "sub-slug3",
        "subcategory-label": "sub-label3"
    },
    {
        "category-slug": "slug4",
        "category-label": "label4",
        "subcategory-slug": "sub-slug4",
        "subcategory-label": "sub-label4"
    }
]
```